# Check if process is runing. if it does - open it

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Well, lets say I got a `process` running.

Lets say, "Skype". And I want to click on a `button` in C# Windows Form App.

When I click on the `button` (Lets call the `button` "Skype Run").

So, when I click on "Skype Run". It will check if the process is running at the moment.

If the process is not running, lets say it will do:

```
MessageBox.Show("Sorry! Skype is not running.")
```

But. If it is running, it will open it up to be the window you are looking at the moment.

So, if you are in Word, and you click on the "Skype Run". And Skype is running and it open the window up. (Just like doing "Switch to" in the task manger in windows.)

If I didn't explained my question very well, please tell me. I just really need the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a code sample here that shows how to do it:

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?p=1757526

Relevant code sample from that post below.  This shows how to finds a process in the  button1_Click event handler.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; //required for APIs
namespace Find

{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Import the FindWindow API to find our window
    [DllImportAttribute("User32.dll")]
    private static extern int FindWindow(String ClassName, String WindowName);

    //Import the SetForeground API to activate it
    [DllImportAttribute("User32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SetForegroundWindow(int hWnd);


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Find the window, using the CORRECT Window Title, for example, Notepad
        int hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Untitled - Notepad");
        if (hWnd > 0) //If found
        {
            SetForegroundWindow(hWnd); //Activate it
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Window Not Found!");
        }


    }
}
}
```

Comment: The same answer as i said down to the guy :(

Comment: Thank god this link isn't dead, otherwise this answer would be.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if a process is already running by using the `Process.GetProcessesByName` static method.

Bringing a specific window to the front can be achieved by using the [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545%28VS.85%29.aspx) Win API

Comment: Ty, so i can get the Process.. but how can i open it? with any "Easy way". your way is very hard to understand..